# Collectd DPDK Telemetry plugin

Tags: dpdk, collectd

I want to use collectd's  DPDK telemetry plugin for exporting metrics from DPDK application. But it won't work. I had uncommented `LoadPlugin dpdk_telemetry`, and my Collectd config for dpdk-telemetry is :

```
<Plugin dpdk_telemetry>
        ClientSocketPath "/var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket"
        DpdkSocketPath "/var/run/dpdk/rte/dpdk_telemetry.v2"
</Plugin>
```

I expect Collectd to work as before, but when I open Collectd output metrics (port 9103 by default), It won't show anything.